# how to save a file to the application folder in electron js

Tags: electron

I originally wanted to save application files to `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local`. But then I realized it wouldn't work for MAC. Is there a way to save the file to an automatically created folder for the application or how to create one for windows, mac and linux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You question is a little confusing. Electron provides a cross-platform way to get the paths to various OS-specific directories: [app.getPath(name)](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/app#appgetpathname). This enables the developer to use the same code to reference these common directories. Electron's documentation is pretty decent.

> **app.getPath**(name)
>
> ```
> name String - You can request the following paths by the name:
>     • home User's home directory.
>     • appData Per-user application data directory, which by default points to:
>         - %APPDATA% on Windows
>         - $XDG_CONFIG_HOME or ~/.config on Linux
>         - ~/Library/Application Support on macOS
>     • userData The directory for storing your app's  
>                configuration files,  
>                which by default it is the appData directory appended 
>                with your app's name.
>     • cache
>     •temp Temporary directory.
>     • exe The current executable file.
>     • module The libchromiumcontent library.
>     • desktop The current user's Desktop directory.
>     • documents Directory for a user's "My Documents".
>     • downloads Directory for a user's downloads.
>     • music Directory for a user's music.
>     • pictures Directory for a user's pictures.
>     • videos Directory for a user's videos.
>     • recent Directory for the user's recent files (Windows only).
>     • logs Directory for your app's log folder.
>     • crashDumps Directory where crash dumps are stored.
> ```
>
> Returns String - A path to a special directory or file associated with
> name. On failure, an Error is thrown.
>
> If app.getPath('logs') is called without called app.setAppLogsPath()
> being called first, a default log directory will be created equivalent
> to calling app.setAppLogsPath() without a path parameter.